# ajax and nonce when JavaScript is in a seperate file

Tags: ajax, javascript, nonce

I'm a little confused about how nonces work with ajax requests. It looks like I'm supposed to use this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/check_ajax_referer

The request looks like this:

```
<?php
//Set Your Nonce
$ajax_nonce = wp_create_nonce( "my-special-string" );
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var data = {
        action: 'my_action',
        security: '<?php echo $ajax_nonce; ?>',
        my_string: 'Hello World!'
    };
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert("Response: " + response);
    });
});
</script>
```

But this approach seems to assume that your JavaScript is mixed in with your PHP, which I is a practice that I like to avoid. When I write an ajax request for a plugin, I use `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')` to separate out the request so it's a bit cleaner to read.

How would I use a nonce in this situation? Do I pass it within the `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')` bit?

Comment: this is a code styling question that is not actually wordpress specific

Answer (score 4):

You can localize your script and pass the nonce and ajax url to the script.
[Learn more about script localization.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

```
function wpse_206839() {

    // Register our script just like we would enqueue it - for WordPress references
    wp_register_script( 'my-special-script', 'directory/my-special-script.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );

    // Create any data in PHP that we may need to use in our JS file
    $local_arr = array(
        'ajaxurl'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'security'  => wp_create_nonce( 'my-special-string' )
    );

    // Assign that data to our script as an JS object
    wp_localize_script( 'my-special-script', 'specialObj', $local_arr );

    // Enqueue our script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-special-script' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_206839' );
```

This will allow us to access our nonce in JS as `console.log( specialObj.security );`